# RDS MySQL 5.7 and Entity Framework

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, amazon-web-services, rds

I just upgraded to the latest MySQL RDS version, from 5.6.

Since we're still using some .NET based on Entity Framework Database First, we cannot run "Update" on the model.
This is a known issue in MySQL 5.7.

A way to fix this, is to run the following on the database:
set global optimizer_switch='derived_merge=OFF'

But, when I do so, I get the usual error about missing SUPER privilege.
I've already added "trust_creators" to my parameters group, and rebooted the instance.

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `optimizer_switch` system variable -- like all configurable system variables -- is configured in the RDS Parameter Group.

Comment: Oh, what a relief!
Thank you so much! :)